# mailbox given does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2 in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

When i try to send a re setting email to user I have this error in symfony 2 :
But it;s working fine in my local server.i cache clear in the server.but same problem,

```
HTTP/1.0 101 Switching Protocols Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 07:11:25 GMT My Error says: 
Address in mailbox given [resetting@.] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. 
with code: 
0
```

I don't understand what is wrong because this address really exist...

Comment: `resetting@.` does exist?

Comment: nop ..normally it's like this in the config_dev.php  'address'=>'resetting@'.$domain,